# What is the best way to go about making an Android App to show speed on UI and to save speed in real-time?

Tags: java, android, database, location, background-task

I need some guidance on what to use for a simple app that shows and saves speed.

Right now I have an app with main activity and LocationService. It does the saving well but i can't find a way to update the UI continuously. I have made other apps with the location code in mainActivity but I want the transmission to continue when screen is closed, So i tried a service but it looks like ill have to implement location provider in mainActivity for the UI?

Is there a functionality im missing?

How do I mkae this app?

Here is my lattest version i CAN'T send speed back to UI.

**LocationService**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(Build.MANUFACTURER+"   "+Build.DEVICE);
DatabaseReference myLiveRef = myRef.child("LiveSpeed");
DatabaseReference myPastsRef = myRef.child("PastSpeeds");
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
LocationCallback locationCallback;
private float speed;

private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();


class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public LocationService getService(){
        return LocationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TAGZ","onBInd");
    return mBinder;
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChanel() ;
    else startForeground(
            1,
            new Notification()
    );
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 1000)
            .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
            .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(500)
            .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(1500)
            .build();

    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            Location location =  locationResult.getLastLocation();

            speed = location.getSpeed()*3.6f;

            myLiveRef.setValue(speed);

            DatabaseReference newPastRef = myPastsRef.push();
            newPastRef.setValue(String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+" ||||||||  "+ speed +" KM/H");
        }
    };
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createNotificationChanel() {
    String notificationChannelId = "Location channel id";
    String channelName = "Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(
            notificationChannelId,
            channelName,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
    );
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("Location updates:")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
  }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST = 99;
    private static final int MY_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_REQUEST = 100;

    TextView textView;
    Intent mServiceIntent;
    Button startServiceBtn, stopServiceBtn;

    private LocationService mLocationService;

    private boolean mBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startServiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.start_service_btn);
        stopServiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.stop_service_btn);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        startServiceBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Background permission");
                            alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.background_location_permission_message));

                            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Start service anyway",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            starServiceFunc();
                                            dialog.dismiss();

                                        }
                                    });

                            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Grant background Permission",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            requestBackgroundLocationPermission();
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });

                            alertDialog.show();

                        }else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            starServiceFunc();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        starServiceFunc();

                    }

                }else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Location permission required");

                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        requestFineLocationPermission();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    } else {
                        requestFineLocationPermission();
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        stopServiceBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopServiceFunc();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocationService.MyBinder binder = (LocationService.MyBinder) service;
            mLocationService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if ( requestCode == MY_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST){
            if (grantResults.length !=0 /*grantResults.isNotEmpty()*/ && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestBackgroundLocationPermission();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                            Uri.parse("lauchmodesdemo.youtube.codetutor.com.speedtest")
                    ));
                }
            }
        }else if (requestCode == MY_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_REQUEST){
            if (grantResults.length!=0 /*grantResults.isNotEmpty()*/ && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Background location Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Background location permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void starServiceFunc(){
        mLocationService = new LocationService();
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, mLocationService.getClass());
        if (!Util.isMyServiceRunning(mLocationService.getClass(), this)) {

            startService(mServiceIntent);
            bindService(mServiceIntent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.service_start_successfully), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.service_already_running), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void stopServiceFunc(){
        if (Util.isMyServiceRunning(mLocationService.getClass(), this)) {
            stopService(mServiceIntent);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service is already stopped!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void requestBackgroundLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                    MY_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    private void requestFineLocationPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,  new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, MY_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

**Util**

```
public class Util {
    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Activity mActivity) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "org.greenrobot:eventbus" to send the current GPS position from foreground service to main activity.

Custom event declaration in eventbus:

```
public static  class NewGPSCoordinates
{
    public final Location mlocation;
       
    public NewGPSCoordinates(Location location)
    {
       this.mlocation = location;
    }
}
```

Sending the GPS data from the foreground service:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvents.NewGPSCoordinates(mLocation));
```

Receiving the gps data in the main activity:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvents.NewGPSCoordinates event)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "NewGPSCoordinates: " + event.mlocation);
}
```

Best regards,
Boyan Iliev

Comment: Looks good ill try this afternoon! thank you.

Comment: Hello where does the NewGPSCoordinates go?

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate and manage all the GPS-related things (LocationManager, listeners, Locations etc.) into the main `Application` Class instead of an `Activity`.
Then you can use the foreground service (that implements a partial `WAKE_LOCK`) only to keep active the app. The service should be bound by the Application class.
Here you can find how to implement a foreground service of this type: [How to keep internet connection alive for a long time on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346792/how-to-keep-internet-connection-alive-for-a-long-time-on-android/69347190#69347190) 
You can browse a real working example of it (Instantaneous speed visualization and recording included) into the free and opensource GPS Logger: https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger 
The app saves all data into the main Application class (`GPSApplication.java`), uses a service to keep active the location in foreground (`GPSService.java`), and uses EventBus to trigger the data update.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting! I have solved it using EventBus. I'll check out the GPS Logger code.

Comment: EventBus is a very good tool, we used it also into GPS Logger.